# Is it possible to stop irrelevant keywords being indexed by Google?

Tags: google-search-console, keywords

My client is in the organic food home delivery business. They are using Shopify to manage online sales.

When we look in Webmaster Tools at the Content Keywords, the bulk of the top twenty keywords are things like weight, quantity, term, price, match, packet, hidden, zero & viewable.

[image: see screenshot]

These are worthless keywords to the business, however, it ranks better for these than many of the 'real' keywords.

If I search for 'organic weight' (See screenshot below), all the other search results are related to weight loss through organic food (or something similar) and Organic Origins are the only organic food business that has nothing to do with weight.

[image: see screenshot]

We have tried adding the schema.org markup to the site to identify these words as elements of a 'thing', but it does not seem to have made any difference.

I have not had this issue with other ecommerce sites I have worked with, however, none of them have been weight based.

Is this a normal thing?

and if not, how do I stop these from being the primary keywords in our data?

Comment: `These are worthless keywords to the business, however, it ranks better for these than many of the 'real' keywords.` Err, no. Content Keywords is not a reflection on your keywords rankings... they simply tell you how often they appear on the site. Just because the site ranks better for quantity doesn't necessary mean its because of keywords, quantity searches are low volume, less competition... and will obviously rank better. Also, your schema is incomplete, missing pricing, quantity and so on...

Comment: We get questions like this a lot! It is frustrating because Google causes soooooooo much unnecessary confusion. The Google Content Keywords list is mostly junk. I have no idea why it still exists or even existed in the first place. What matters is *how* people find your site. This list does not reflect that. Chuck this list and forget about it. Use the rest of Search Console and Google Analytics to assess how your site performs in search. Cheers!!